# Program 'psr.exe' failed to run: StandardOutputEncoding is only supported when standard output is redirected

Tags: powershell

We are trying to run PSR on a remote machine and we are getting the following error .

Command:

```
psr /start /gui 0 /sc 1 /sketch 1 /output  "[outFilePath]"
```

```
Error : [WTL.Error] Message="System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException: 

Program 'psr.exe' failed to run: StandardOutputEncoding is only supported when standard output is redirected.
```

Any help will be much appreciated .

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) yet?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the error is related to the fact that on Windows, in ***Windows PowerShell* and in *PowerShell (Core) up to v7.2.x***, **PowerShell doesn't allocate a console window in *remote* calls** - this has been **fixed in *PowerShell v7.3+***.

While CLIs typically allocate a console *on demand*<sup>[1]</sup>, it appears that `psr.exe` doesn't do that, which may explain the error message.

**Workaround**: Allocate a console explicitly in your remote session, before calling `psr`:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $someComputer {

  # Explicitly allocate a console.
  # Note: This incurs a performance penalty due to on-demand compilation.
  $null = (Add-Type -Name Aux -Namespace WinApi -PassThru -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern bool AllocConsole();')::AllocConsole()

  psr /start /gui 0 /sc 1 /sketch 1 /output C:\path\to\out.file

}
```

---

<sup>[1] Combined with the absence of a session-wide console in a remote PowerShell call targeting Windows PowerShell or PowerShell (Core) up to v7.2.x, this can cause *character-encoding problems* - see [GitHub issue #15128](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15128) for details.</sup>